# get max duplicate item indexes in a list using python

Tags: python, list

As someone here pointed me out, for getting the max duplicated item in a list this can be used:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> mylist = [20, 20, 25, 25, 30, 30]
>>> max(k for k,v in Counter(mylist).items() if v>1)
30
```

but, what if i want to get the indexes instead of the values, being here `[4, 5]`

any help??

Regards...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> mylist = [20, 20, 25, 25, 30, 30]
>>> D = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i,x in enumerate(mylist):
        D[x].append(i)


>>> D[max(k for k,v in D.items() if len(v)>1)]
[4, 5]
```